# I am getting an undefined array key message in the update page - how to solve this error?

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

In the update page when I click the update button this error is showing:

> Warning: Undefined array key "updateId"

How to solve this? Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

//id geting from the url

$id = $_GET['updateId'] ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM seriescurd WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// echo $row['fname'];

///show whatever the data  come from the database
$f_name = $row['fname'];
$l_name = $row['lname'];
$email = $row['email'];
$mobile = $row['mobile'];

//show updated data
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $f_name = $_POST['f_name']; 
    $l_name = $_POST['l_name'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `seriescurd` SET `fname`='$f_name',`lname`='$l_name',`email`='$email',
    `mobile`='$mobile' WHERE id='$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        echo "data updated";
    } else {
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
   <div class="container my-5">
        <form action="">
            <div class=" form-group mb-3">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $f_name ?>">
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group mb-3">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="l_name" autocomplete="off" value="<?      



php echo $l_name ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo   $email ?>">
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group mb-3">
                <label>mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" autocomplete="off"value="<?php echo   $email ?>">
            </div> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" name="update">update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the update page code in the index page:

```
<a href="update.php?updateId=">update</a>
```

Comment: The code expects an `updateId` parameter to be supplied in the URL.  The error message indicates that it is not present.

Comment: Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection - I strongly recommend you do not pass user-supplied values directly into SQL code that you then execute.  Instead, I recommend using prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: `$_GET` fetches parameters from the URL. Evidently the URL you submitted to  PHP didn't contain  anything like `?updateId=123` at the end of it. This is also suggested by the fact you've got `action=""` as the form's action URL. It'll just submit to the page. If you had the ID in the URL which _built_ the form, then you should transmit it onwards either in the form's action, or by putting the ID into a hidden field of the  form and then using `$_POST` to retrieve it when the form is submitted.

Comment: Also I'm not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their name (such as `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Comment: @NicoHaase SQL injection is certainly a big problem in this code but it's not the cause of the undefined array key error, and therefore that question shouldn't be proposed as a duplicate. I've closed with a more appropriate one, and removed the SQL injection one.